# From an ear file's application.xml deployment descriptor, how do I override a @ManagedBean's @EJB reference?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, managed-bean

I have a `@ManagedBean` in my `.ear` file's `lib` directory.

In that `@ManagedBean` I have this:

```
@EJB(name = "ejb/Fred") // declares ejb reference and names it
private Fred fred;
```

In my `.ear` file's `META-INF/application.xml` I have this:

```
<ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Fred</ejb-ref-name> <!-- targets reference declared above -->
  <local>com.foobar.Fred</local>
  <ejb-link>some-jar.jar#FredBean</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

GlassFish 3.1.2.2 happily processes this and does the right thing for dozens of my *EJBs* that have `@EJB`-annotated fields in them with names of `ejb/Fred`: they all get `FredBean` from the `some-jar.jar` EJB jar as their implementation.  No muss, no fuss, as the spec intended.

But when it comes to `@ManagedBean`s with these `@EJB`-annotated fields, the binding doesn't happen.

GlassFish 3.1.2.2 throws an exception saying that there are many `Fred` implementations present (which there are in my case—why I'm in this `<ejb-local-ref>` situation in the first place), so it can't inject something into my `fred` field.

That is, I cannot target my `@ManagedBean`-hosted `@EJB` reference named `ejb/Fred` from configuration.

The Managed Bean 1.0 "specification" says, somewhat ominously:

> A Managed Bean does not have its own component-scoped “`java:comp`” namespace. For this reason, Managed Beans should **define resources** [emphasis mine] in the “`java:module`” namespace or
>   above.

More specifically, clearly this means that I cannot use the `name` attribute of the `@EJB` annotation, because, as its documentation reads:

> The logical name of the ejb reference within the declaring component's (e.g., java:comp/env) environment.

[**Edit:** the EJB specification committee just changed the language here in response to this question; this actually raises some more questions—it was apparently always intended that you should be able to use "absolute" resource names in the `name()` element.]

[**Edit:** I realized that you can control the scope of your EJB reference's name with one of the `java:module` or `java:app` prefixes, per [this](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#How_do_I_define_my_own_portable_global).  Perhaps the answer is to define all of my `<ejb-local-ref>`s twice in `META-INF/application.xml`: once for component environment names, and once for `java:app` names?]

[**Edit:** Declaring a reference as `@EJB(name = "java:app/ejb/Fred")` or @EJB(name = "java:module/ejb/Fred")`and targeting it as that in my`application.xml`'s`` elements doesn't work either.  I believe that this may be a straight up bug.]

[**Edit:** David Blevins' `lookup()` solution works as far as it goes.  `lookup()` is not an alternative to `name()`, but rather to `mappedName()` and `beanName()`, neither of which, ideally, I would want to specify on these references, as repackaging would then be a nightmare. Additionally, automatic reference wiring then goes out the window entirely; using `lookup()` means you're telling the container the Deployer or Assembler will manually bind a reference here and the container should lay off.  A nightmare for a sprawling enterprise app.]

**Is there any way to use an `application.xml`-level `<ejb-link>` element to target `@ManagedBean`-hosted `@EJB` references?**

[**Edit:** I've filed a [GlassFish bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20739) with a test case.]

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `lookup` attribute of the `@EJB` annotation.  It was added in Java EE 6 and likely not visible to your IDE unless you're on Java 7 or have added the right jars to your Java 6 JVM's endorsed dir.  In the `lookup` attribute you would put the jndi name, `java:app/ejb/Fred` or any other name under `java:app`.

Then in your application.xml create a name for `java:app/ejb/Fred` and link it to the desired EJB.

```
<ejb-local-ref>
  <ejb-ref-name>java:app/ejb/Fred</ejb-ref-name>
  <local>com.foobar.Fred</local>
  <ejb-link>some-jar.jar#FredBean</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

If this doesn't work, you might be out of luck.

#### Note on @ManagedBean

`@ManagedBean` is underdefined and undertested.  It was added late in Java EE 6 as a placeholder in for future development and hasn't been further developed.  I don't recommend using it.

You might, try switching it to an `@javax.ejb.Singleton` or `@javax.ejb.Stateless` service instead of `@ManagedBean`, though ideally your POJO JAX-RS service should have dependency injection even without adding `@ManagedBean`.

If you find it helpful, I can confirm all of the above work in TomEE.  I'm sure GlassFish would be more than willing to accept patches and help in this area.

Comment: Aha, so `lookup()` is sort of a JNDI-centric replacement of sorts for `name()`?  I'll give that a shot.  Regarding `@ManagedBean`: Yes, I know it. Jersey unfortunately requires it (!!!) for `@EJB` injection inside resource classes.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Follow up question before I replace thousands of lines of code: will the presence of a `lookup()` attribute now _require_ me to provide `<ejb-link>` overrides, even in those cases where there's only one candidate EJB for the container to inject?  Or will it (please please please say yes) still fall back on that default behavior where possible?

Comment: This works.  Unfortunately, if I go this route, then I have to provide explicit configuration for everything so annotated.  I only want to provide configuration for those cases where disambiguation of references is required.  http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#How_do_I_define_my_own_portable_global seems to indicate that `name = "java:app/ejb/Fred"` might be legal, but the specs are silent. Trying this next.

Comment: The `@EJB` `name()` attribute does _not_ accept a non-relative path, despite what any EJB FAQ might otherwise claim.  So the answer to my question is effectively no: short of specifying a `lookup()` attribute value, and then being forced to manually resolve all such references, overriding `@EJB` references present in `@ManagedBean`s is impossible.